# How to adjust shoe clearance after installing new brake shoes?

Tags: brakes

I just finished installing new brake shoes on a 1997 Y10 Nissan Wingroad. The image below is from the service manual and shows the page with installation instructions (starting about halfway down the page).

[image]

Under **INSTALLATION** (halfway down the page) it says, "**Always perform shoe clearance adjustment. Refer to BR-35**."

At the bottom of the page (number 9), it says, "**Adjust parking brake. Refer to BR-35**".

The section on adjusting the parking brake (BR-35) is attached below:

[image]

In videos I've watched online they all said to manually adjust the clearance using the star adjuster until the shoes are just touching the drum and then back off the adjuster a few clicks.

Comment: So use the adjusters until the shoe touches then back 2 or 3 clicks...

Comment: @SolarMike, yes that's normally how it's done but in the service manual for my car it says to set the clearance by adjusting the parking brake but the way it's explained is a bit confusing.

Answer (score 1):

First adjust the shoe clearance by adjusting the star wheel as shown on the first diagram you sent. Adjust so that the shoes lightly contact the drum then back off a couple clicks. Then adjust parking brake at handle per instructions from your second diagram. These are two separate adjustments.

Comment: Nowhere does it say anything about adjusting the star wheel except to shorten it (no. 3 under installation in the first image). Under Installation in the first image it says, "Always perform shoe clearance adjustment. Refer to BR-35." The second image is BR-35.

Comment: What I wrote is common procedure for drum brake adjustment with the type of parts installed on this system. Installation instructions can be vague at best sometimes. But if you do not have complete confidence in your installation you might want to bring it in to a shop and pay a little for adjustments. You can take this opportunity to ask a few questions and learn for the next time.

Comment: The first step in the instructions for adjusting the parking brake involve depressing the brake pedal at least 10 times which I assume will cause the automatic adjuster to set the correct clearance between brake shoes and drum.

Comment: @jrcollins pressing the brake several times is to make sure the brake shoes are positioned correctly on their supports. if that was sufficient for the automatic adjusters then that would be it. But if manual adjusters are fitted then they need to be used.

Comment: @SolarMike, when pressing the brake pedal, I could hear the automatic adjusters clicking. After that I adjusted the parking brake. There were a few squeaks when first using the brakes but now everything seems to be working ok and the car is braking in a straight line. However, I jacked up each of the rear wheels and noticed that there's some slight friction between shoes and drum when spinning one of the wheels while the other one is turning freely. Not sure if that's anything to be concerned about or not.

Answer (score 0):

The adjustment of the parking brake handle is separate from the brake shoe adjuster inside the drums.

You can adjust the clearance brake shoe/drum a bit when you put the drum back on,the drum should slide on quite easy.

The rest of the adjustment is done by pulling the parking brake handle and then pressing the brake pedal down while you release the parking brake handle then take your foot off the brake pedal and pull the parking brake handle(repeat as many times as it takes to get the brakes to function properly(you should be able to hear a ticking sound when you release the parking brake handle if the adjuster works as it should).

When the adjustment of the shoe/drum is done you can adjust the parking brake handle IF you need to do it.

Trust yourself YOU can do this!!